# Вывод записей из базы на определенное количество месяцев

Tags: дата, mysql

Всем привет.

Допустим, человек выбрал, что его новость будет видна 3 месяца.
При добавлении новости дата старта показа пишется в формате 0000-00-00 00:00:00
Количество месяцев записывается целыми числами.

Не могу понять, как мне в запросе к текущий дате прибавить определенное количество месяцев, чтобы составить уже условие. Главное, чтобы не просто дни учитывались, но и время, когда добавили новость.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Достаточно просто указать `+ INTERVAL N MONTH`:

    SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH

Вместо `MONTH` может быть `DAY`, `WEEK` etc

Comment: ...или посчитать дату окончания видимости сразу и уже ее записать в базу.

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо большое.!


@Yura Ivanov, да, так лучше наверное будет?

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

Для того, чтобы прибавить к календарному значению интервал, можно воспользоваться ключевым словом `INTERVAL`, например, если дата хранится в поле `created_at`, получить дату спустя 3 месяца можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH AS finished_at
FROM
  news
```

Извлечь актуальные для показа новости можно при помощи запроса

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  news
WHERE
  NOW() >= created_at AND
  NOW() <= created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```